# Linear dependent, and linear independent, linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vector v = [
1
2
], write some vector w that is linearly dependent with v, and some other
vector r that is linearly independent of v.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $n$ vectors are linearly dependent if there exist constants/scalars $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n $ s.t. $c_1 \alpha_1 + c_2 \alpha_2 + \dots c_n \alpha_n = 0$  where $c_i's$ are not all zero, i.e. there exists some non-zero $c_i$.

So, for $n = 2$ we want $c_1 \alpha_1 + c_2 \alpha_2 = 0$. Atleast one of $c_1$ and $c_2$ is non-zero, so divide the equation by that non-zero scalar to get $\alpha_1 = c \alpha_2$

And, by definition vectors that are not linearly dependent are linearly independent.